# Is there a way to lazy load NgModule without Route?

Tags: angular

I have 3 pages that should not have its own route.

1. Slot and Tickets page.
2. Your Details page.
3. Payment page.

This is because the Desktop UX flow is to scroll to the next section. Meanwhile, the Desktop section is to scroll to the next page. So, having route only for the Mobile version is not desirable.

Right now I am using *ngIf to simulate navigating to the next page for the Mobile components. The problem is since I import all of the components to the Mobile NgModule, the bundle size for this feature is already at 700 KB. Not big but I believe we can reduce it by lazy load.

Is there Angular way to do this?